# Jquery. Почему не работает снова старт на таймере

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

Создаю таймер, с тремя кнопками старт, пауза и сброс.
После паузы не запускается снова старт. Буду благодарна за любую подсказку.

```
<div>
<span id="minutes">00</span>:
<span id="seconds">00</span>
</div>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
   
<script>          
   let second = 0;
   let minute = 0;
   let beginning = false;

   let addOneMinute = () => {
     minute++;
     if(minute < 10) {
      $('#minutes').text('0' + minute)
     } else if(minute >= 10){
      $('#minutes').text(minute)     
     }    
   };
      
let timer = () => {
  if(!beginning) {
    second++;
    if(second < 10) {
     $('#seconds').text('0' + second)
    } else if(second <= 60){
     $('#seconds').text(second)     
    } else if(second > 60) {
      second = 0;
      addOneMinute();
    }
  }  
}

let pause = $('#pause').on('click', function() {
  beginning = true;
 clearInterval(start)
});

$('#start').on('click', function() {
 let start = setInterval(timer, 1000); 
});

$('#reset').on('click', function() {
    clearInterval(timer);
  beginning = false;
  second = 0;
  minute = 0;
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/botagoz/Lgy7oh1b/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваша функция основывается назначении beginning

```
let timer = () => {
if(!beginning) {...}}
```

В функции "пауза" вы устанавливаете значение `beginning = true`, но при "старте" вы его не меняете.
Потому у вас этот метод и не срабатывает.

И еще, область видимости переменных `let` ограничивается блоком. Т.е. переменная `start` у вас будет видна только в функции.
Потому когда вы обращаетесь к `clearInterval(start);`, метод будет работать *не так, как вы бы хотели*.

В итоге, вам необходимо объявить `start` в самом начале, чтобы она была видна для **обеих** функций.

```
<script>   
  let start = 0;
```

И в функции `start` не забыть изменить значение для `beginning`:

```
 $('#start').on('click', function() {
    beginning = false;
    start = setInterval(timer, 1000); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что дело в том, что у вас в функции start нет присвоения переменной

```
 beginning = false;
```

А в условии таймера есть проверка:

```
if(!beginning)
```

А в ситуации когда после паузы мы жмем  старт сейчас у нас значение:

```
beginning = true;
```

По этому таймер и не стартует,т.к не проходит по условию.